# How to make regression with categorical and non-categorical features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What is the right way to make regression with sklearn if I have multiple features, but some features are categorical and some are not?

I was trying 'ColumnTransformer' but i'm not sure that I'm doing it good:

```
features = df[['grad', 'oblast', 'tip',
               'parcela', 'bruto', 'neto', 'osnova',
               'neto/bruto', 'zauzetost', 'sipovi', 'garaza',
               'nadzemno', 'podzemno', 'tavanica', 'fasada']]


results = df[['ukupno gradjevinski din']]


trans = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('onehot', OneHotEncoder(), ['grad', 'oblast', 'tip', 'garaza', 'tavanica', 'fasada']),
                                        ('normalizer', Normalizer(), ['parcela', 'bruto', 'neto', 'osnova', 'neto/bruto', 'zauzetost', 'nadzemno'])],
                          remainder='passthrough') # Default is to drop untransformed columns

features = trans.fit_transform(features)
```

When I print corr() for some features, I see that there are big correlation  between them and the results:

```
print(df[['parcela', 'bruto', 'neto', 'osnova', 'ukupno gradjevinski din']].corr().to_string())

                          parcela     bruto      neto    osnova  ukupno gradjevinski din
parcela                  1.000000  0.929939  0.930039  0.987574                 0.911690
bruto                    0.929939  1.000000  0.998390  0.943996                 0.878914
neto                     0.930039  0.998390  1.000000  0.946102                 0.889850
osnova                   0.987574  0.943996  0.946102  1.000000                 0.937064
ukupno gradjevinski din  0.911690  0.878914  0.889850  0.937064                 1.000000
```

The problem is that I have stacked 7-8 regression models and I'm evaluating them with `cross-validation`, but I get scores form -10 to -80, and is not normal to me.

```
regressors = [
              ["Bagging Regressor TREE", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=15))],
              ["Bagging Regressor FOREST", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100))],
              ["Bagging Regressor linear", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = LinearRegression(normalize=True))],
              ["Bagging Regressor lasso", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = Lasso(normalize=True))],
              ["Bagging Regressor SVR rbf", BaggingRegressor(base_estimator = SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C=10.0, gamma='scale'))],
              ["Extra Trees Regressor", ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators = 150)],
              ["K-Neighbors Regressor", KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=1)]]


for reg in regressors:

     scores = cross_val_score(reg[1], features, results, cv=5, scoring='r2')

     scores = np.average(scores)
     print(reg[0], scores)
```

Every time when it comes to "Bagging Regressor linear" it gives me the error:

```
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

Even If I run my regression models with just features that you see in corr(), i get the same results.

Can you tell me more about the promblem that I have?

Answer (score 0):

One way to combine categorical and non-categorical features to a regression model is to use one-hot encoding on the categorical features. For concreteness, if you have a categorical feature which may have 3 values, then you create 3 columns which you fill with 0s and 1s depending on its one-hot encoded value.

You may find the details with a clear explanation, examples and an implementation on the page 213 in the section One-Hot-Encoding (Dummy Variables) from the book [Introduction to Machine Learning with Python: A Guide for Data Scientists](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449369413).

Comment: Thats what "ColumnTransformer" do. But still I get very bad results, and I have big correlation